# How to copy tables from multiple Word files to separate worksheets in Excel, naming the worksheet the name of the Word doc?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have used the VBA macro below to put multiple tables from multiple Word documents into one worksheet in Excel.

I want the multiple tables from each different Word doc to go into different worksheets with the worksheets named the name of the Word doc.

```vb
Sub ImportWordTable()

    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim arrFileList As Variant, FileName As Variant
    Dim tableNo As Integer                            'table number in Word

    Dim tableStart As Integer
    Dim tableTot As Integer
    Dim Target As Range

    'On Error Resume Next

    arrFileList = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc; *.docx),*.doc;*.docx", 2, _
                                              "Browse for file containing table to be imported", , True)

    If Not IsArray(arrFileList) Then Exit Sub         '(user cancelled import file browser)

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True

    Range("A:AZ").ClearContents
    Set Target = Range("A1")

    For Each FileName In arrFileList
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)

        With WordDoc
            tableNo = WordDoc.tables.Count
            tableTot = WordDoc.tables.Count
            If tableNo = 0 Then
                MsgBox WordDoc.Name & " contains no tables", vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"

            ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
                tableNo = InputBox(WordDoc.Name & " contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
                                   "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
            End If

            For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
                With .tables(tableStart)
                    .Range.Copy
                    'Target.Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                    Target.Activate
                    ActiveSheet.Paste

                    Set Target = Target.Offset(.Rows.Count + 2, 0)
                End With
            Next tableStart

            .Close False
        End With

    Next FileName

    WordApp.Quit

    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following macro. It allows you to choose the source folder. It creates a new worksheet for each document and outputs all tables from that document one below the other, with an empty row in between. Except for text wrapping, table formatting is preserved as much as possible.

```
Sub GetTableData()
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model.
'See under the VBE's Tools|References.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, wdTbl As Word.Table
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, WkBk As Workbook, WkSht As Worksheet, r As Long
strFolder = GetFolder: If strFolder = "" Then GoTo ErrExit
Set WkBk = ActiveWorkbook
'Disable any Word Alerts
wdApp.DisplayAlerts =wdAlertsNone
'Disable any auto macros in the documents being processed
wdApp.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  Set WkSht = WkBk.Sheets.Add
  WkSht.Name = Split(strFile, ".doc")(0)
  With wdDoc
    For Each wdTbl In .Tables
      With wdTbl.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "[^13^l]"
        .Replacement.Text = "¶"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      End With
      r = WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      If r > 1 Then r = r + 2
      wdTbl.Range.Copy
      WkSht.Paste Destination:=WkSht.Range("A" & r)
    Next
    WkSht.UsedRange.Replace What:="¶", Replacement:=Chr(10), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
  End With
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
ErrExit:
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing: Set WkBk = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim oFolder As Object
    GetFolder = ""
    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
    If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, after I select the folder, nothing happens. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Did you add the required reference to the Word object model - as mentioned at the top of the code?

Comment: Just enabled "Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library" but now, after successfully naming the first sheet but not inputting any content, I'm getting a _Microsoft Excel is waiting on another application to complete an OLE action_. Do I also need to enable something in Word? Do I need to re-prioritize the references in VBE?

Comment: Realized I had to click "allow read-only access" or something to the word doc before the code could run. Once I allowed this, the first worksheet was populated and named correctly, but afterwards I received another 1004 error.

Comment: Evidently, you have various documents with access restrictions, perhaps even a mailmerge main document. I've modified the code to work around most such issues, though it's not going to help where you need a password to open the document...

Comment: When I try this, I get Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object. Am using MS VBA 7.1 on a Mac...

Comment: The code is for Office on a Windows PC, not for the Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following, perhaps. Since I can't replicate your documents my test environment wasn't identical...

The following code declares a `Word.Table` and a `Excel.Worksheet` object to the list of declared variables.

The Worksheet object is set to `ActiveSheet` and later to each added worksheet. Using an object instead of a selection or "active" something is almost always preferable - then it's clearer for both human and VBA what's is meant. `ws` is also used to more exactly define the `Range` specifications.

Before looping the tables, the worksheet `Name` is set to the value stored in `Filename` for the Word document.

The Table object is set to the `WordDoc.tables(tableStart)` table. It's more efficient to work with an object instead of querying the full "path" to an object each time. It's also easier to read.

Before looping to the next Word document a new worksheet is added.

```
Sub ImportWordTable()

    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim tbl As Object
    Dim arrFileList As Variant, FileName As Variant
    Dim tableNo As Integer                            'table number in Word

    Dim tableStart As Integer
    Dim tableTot As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Range

    'On Error Resume Next

    arrFileList = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc; *.docx),*.doc;*.docx", 2, _
                                              "Browse for file containing table to be imported", , True)

    If Not IsArray(arrFileList) Then Exit Sub         '(user cancelled import file browser)

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

    For Each FileName In arrFileList
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
        With WordDoc
            tableNo = WordDoc.tables.Count
            tableTot = WordDoc.tables.Count
            If tableNo = 0 Then
                MsgBox WordDoc.Name & " contains no tables", vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"

            ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
                tableNo = InputBox(WordDoc.Name & " contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
                                   "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
            End If

            ws.Name = FileName
            For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
                Set Target = ws.Range("A1")
                Set tbl = .tables(tableStart)
                With tbl
                    .Range.Copy
                    'Target.Parent.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                    Target.Activate
                    ws.Paste

                    Set Target = Target.Offset(.Rows.Count + 2, 0)
                End With
            Next tableStart

            .Close False
        End With
        Set ws = ws.Parent.Worksheets.Add

    Next FileName
    ws.Delete 'the last sheet is one too many
    WordApp.Quit

    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you and no need to apologize at all! However, I am getting a "1004 - application-defined or object-defined error" message right after I select the word docs and "enter a table to start from".

Comment: Which line of code, specifically? Assigning the name? This is a part I couldn't test, not having the files. Possibly some characters in `Filename` aren't valid for naming a worksheet - that's not something I can check. For the moment, try commenting out `Filename` and substitute something like "mySheet" + tableStart. If that runs then you can research what you need to do to `Filename` to make it acceptable.

Comment: Thank you. No specific line of code was shown to cause the 1004. I tried re-running the code as is after changing the word doc names to "file1", "file2", etc. Same 1004 error. Could you clarify what you mean by commenting out `Filename` and substituting it what you mentioned?

Comment: Then use F8 to step through the code to determine where the error is occurring.

Comment: Tried F8. First, it highlights the first line, then `arrFileList = ...`, then allows me to select files, then error, then highlights `Exit Sub         '(user cancelled import file browser)`

Comment: @hunterstevens In your original question you give the impression that selecting the files is working. People responding assume that and concentrate on the multiple tables aspect. Apparently you don't have the file selection working. I suggest you open a new question to solve that.

Comment: In my oroginal code, I was able to select multiple word files and sucessfully run the code as expected. I just wanted new/updated vba code that would put the tables from each word doc into separate worksheets, while also naming the sheets the name of the word doc.

Comment: @hunterstevens You say you're getting the error after you select the files - then that's where the problem is.

Comment: If my files work for my original code, I'm not sure what needs to be done to the files to make them run with your code. If my files are just named file1, file2, etc, shouldn't your code run?

Comment: I didn't change anything in that part of the code, nor have I analysed it.