# Going through the folder of word files in order to copy all word tables to excel file with seperate sheet per word file error

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

As mentioned in title I have a folder with word files and I want to copy from these files all tables to seperate sheets. I have tried to adapt the solutions from the internet but none of them works (or maybe I did not apply them correctly).

The error I encounter is

> 1004 "Method 'Paste' of object '_Worksheet' failed"

or sometimes it cannot copy/paste due to merged cells.
It shows on line code:

```
WkSht.Paste Destination:=WkSht.Range("A" & r)
```

What is strange when I rerun the macro it does go properly trough all files in folder. But I have to kill the word sometimes in task managers due to OLE error

> "Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action."

choosing File, Options, Advanced, and under General  Ignore other applications that use DDE does not help.

```
Public wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, wdTbl As Word.Table
Public strFolder As String, strFile As String, WkBk As Workbook, WkSht As Worksheet, r As Long

Sub GetTableData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x As Integer

strFolder = GetFolder: If strFolder = "" Then GoTo ErrExit
Set WkBk = ActiveWorkbook
wdApp.WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc*", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
Set WkSht = WkBk.Sheets.Add
x = x + 1
WkSht.Name = Mid(strFile, 20, 29) & x

With wdDoc
For Each wdTbl In .Tables
  With wdTbl.Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[^13^l]"
    .Replacement.Text = "¶"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
  r = WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  If r > 1 Then r = r + 2
  wdTbl.Range.Copy
  WkSht.Paste Destination:=WkSht.Range("A" & r)
Next
WkSht.UsedRange.Replace What:="¶", Replacement:=Chr(10), LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows
.Close SaveChanges:=False
End With
strFile = Dir()
Wend
ErrExit:
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing: Set WkBk = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function

Function sheet_exists(sheet_to_find As String) As Boolean

Dim work_sheet As Worksheet

sheet_exists = False
For Each work_sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sheet_to_find = work_sheet.Name Then
        sheet_exists = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next work_sheet

End Function
```

Comment: The first thing you need to change is `Dim wdApp as New Word.Application`. Remove `New` and in another line use `Set wdApp = New Word.Application`. VBA won't complain when `New` is used in the declaration, but the object created like this can't be managed correctly. This might be the cause of the second error reported.

Comment: Also, don't Quit the Word.Application before setting wdDoc to Nothing.

Comment: Hello @Cindy Meister, thank you for your feedback. I have applied suggested improvements, however I am still encountering the error 
inline '1004 "Method 'Paste' of object '_Worksheet' failed' on <pre>WkSht.Paste Destination:=WkSht.Range("A" & r)"<code>

Comment: But the second and subsequent runs are successful?

Comment: That is correct, I have run it multiple times on different folders with different files and it keeps showing up.

Maybe I should remove ` .Close SaveChanges:=False` in order to keep word files active as it might be an issue with closing the source copy files too fast?

Comment: Try it yourself and see - it's difficult for anyone else to trouble-shoot this since we don't know the content that's causing problems. I recommend you use the [edit] link below the question to change the description and the code to the current state (i.e. without the second error). That will make it easier for people to concentrate on that aspect of the problem. Then, provide sample Word content that's *not* working.

Comment: @Fiskatela There is nothing wrong with the code (Cindy's comments notwithstanding), most of which it seems you've lifted from my post at: https://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?8900-Help-with-VBA-to-extract-data-from-Word-to-Excel. Your 'sheet_exists'  function, though, serves no purpose and there's no benefit in moving the variable declarations as you've done. You might try repairing your Office installation (via Windows Control Panel > Programs > Programs & Features > Microsoft Office (version) > Change > Repair). Other than that, check the table content in the erroring document.

Comment: Or maybe you got it from my post in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52223777/vba-code-that-copies-tables-from-multiple-word-files-to-separate-worksheets-in-e